# Creating AWS Lambda function using boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, aws-lambda

Im trying to follow the tutorial [AWS Lambda Functions Made Easy - codeburst](https://codeburst.io/aws-lambda-functions-made-easy-1fae0feeab27).

However I don't understand this code snippet:

```
export VIRTUALENV='venv_lambda'
export ZIP_FILE='lambda.zip'
export PYTHON_VERSION='python2.7'# Zip dependencies from virtualenv, and main.py
cd $VIRTUALENV/lib/$PYTHON_VERSION/site-packages/
zip -r9 ../../../../$ZIP_FILE *
cd ../../../../
zip -g $ZIP_FILE main.py
```

1. Am I just exporting the virtual environment and the main.py as a
   zip?
2. What does export do here?
3. What am I suppose to replace the middle part of `zip -r9
   ../../../../$ZIP_FILE *` with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You are creating a zip file that includes your `main.py` as well as everything in your virtual environment's `site_packages` directory (your pip-installed dependencies).

2) `export` is a bash builtin command that sets a variable in the current environment *and* the environment of any future child processes. In this case it doesn't seem like it's used in any child process and probably not needed.

3) Nothing. That `../../../../$ZIP_FILE` is the relative path back to where the resulting zip file will be located in your original directory (before the `cd` command).

The key is to make a zip containing your code and dependencies all at the top level of the zip archive, as opposed to having dependencies nested several levels down in `site_packages` as they are locally.

Answer (score 0):

This is a VERY old tutorial. I highly recommend abandoning it and trying some of the frameworks (e.g. [Serverless](https://serverless.com/blog/category/guides-and-tutorials/) or [AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html)). Here comes a [nice official tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html) of AWS SAM.

Please note that boto3 is a Python package that is a Python driver (middleware) for the AWS API. Theoretically, you can create a function with it, but you still have to do the packaging and deployment of the lambda code separately then. And there is a lot of extra configuration work that frameworks can do for you. Definitely not a beginner level.

As of your question: `export` command in the example above is an Operating System (not Python) command to create/update some ENVIRONMENT-al variable in your OS session. They can be used from any language/application that you invoke during that session. In this code snippet you first `export ZIP_FILE` and then use it as `$ZIP_FILE` this is `bash` syntax. Same fo `VIRTUALENV` and `PYTHON_VERSION` - these are just string variables.

P.S. Python 2.7 will retire very soon: https://pythonclock.org/ Abandon that, as well. AWS Lambda has native support for the two latest (as of today) versions of Python: 3.6 and 3.7.

Comment: yeah it looks quite outdated. Could you tell me what *zip -r9
../../../../$ZIP_FILE * should be replaced with? Is it asking me to specify the directory to zip file or create a directory with zip file in it?